# Filtering link associated with view based on permissions

Tags: views

I have a view, print a list of meetings. Using the 'custom text' option I added a link related to the meeting - 'clone meeting'. If the person has a particular permission for the meeting then I would like display the link, but only then.

I don't want to filter the whole record, so can't see a way using hook_views_pre_render(). I could regex the rendered content in hook_views_post_render(), but this seems error prone. How should the conditional link be added?

Drupal 7. Views 7.x-3.5.

Comment: Use views php to use PHP code in 'custom text' field

Comment: Yes - that is what I did.

Comment: So that is the answer - also created static method so that it would autoload easily. <?php 
if (MeetingClonePerms::accessCloning($row->nid)) {
  print  '<a href="/meetingclone/clone/5017?group_audience=28">clone</a>';
}
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by:

1. Installing views php
2. Creating a static class with the permission logic in it.
3. Editing the view to have Global:PHP as a field.

The class is autoloaded via module.info file. files[] = 'MyClass.inc'. Static function is just a facade to the module function so that it will be in scope.

```
class MeetingClonePerms {
  public static function accessCloning($nid) {
    // Calls module function here.
```

The php in Global:PHP views field is in 'output code':

```
<?php 
if (MeetingClonePerms::accessCloning($row->nid)) {
  print  '<a href="/meetingclone/clone/' . $row->nid . '">clone</a>';
}
?>
```